# Best way to extract specific paragraph from file data

Tags: java

Hi i am looking to find out the best way to extract specific paragraph from file using java.

From the following data i need to extract data from   **"D & A"**  to  **Testing1- End**  and from 2nd para 
 **"D & A"**  to  **Testing2- End**

Please guid me best way to get this values. Thanks
//File Data (Eg : )

```
Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata
Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata
Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata
```

D and A
Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 
Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 
Testing1Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1- End

```
                                                Date 11/30/11           Page    2
```

D and A
Testing2  Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2
 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2
 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2
                                                    Date 11/30/11           Page    3
D and A
Testing2  Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2
 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2
 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 -End

Comment: @Ingo i want it in java... I tried with linenumber but not able to get value. Plz help

Comment: Nobody can help you there, unless you give more specific information about what exactly the problem is. Reading the file? Storing the data? Traversing the data, looking for the paragraph delimiters? You know, up to now your question is equivalent to "Please write this program for me."

Comment: @Ingo thanks for your reply. My problem is i am not able write any program.. I want a way how to get few specific data from file. plz refer my post. Thanks again !!!

Comment: If the file is text based use a BufferedReader to read the data. You'll need a boolean that indicates if you're collecting data or not. Set the boolean to true when you find the starting delimiter, false when you find the closing delimiter. While the boolean is true you should be collecting your data in whatever object is most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I would read in the file line by line, something like [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml) tutorial.

You can then check if the line contains a certain string.

```
boolean readFollowingLines = false;
ArayList<String> paragraph=new ArayList<String>();
if( string.indexOf("1- End") > 0 ) // maybe >= 0, not shure
    readFollowingLines = false;
if (readFollowingLines)
   paragraph.add(string);
if( string.indexOf("D and A") > 0 ) // maybe >= 0, not shure
   readFollowingLines = true;
```

If you want more then one paragraph you need to extend this a little.
Anyway, I'd probably do it something like this

Answer (score 1):

for an input like this

> Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata Testingdata
>
> D and A
>   Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1- End
>
> ```
>                                               Date 11/30/11           Page    2
> ```
>
> D and A
>   Testing2  Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2
>
> ```
>                                               Date 11/30/11           Page    3
> ```
>
> D and A
>   Testing2  Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2- End

The following Regex will help you out

```
    String input="";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/to/text/file")); //file path will be something like "D:/test1.txt" or "/home/naishe/test1.txt"
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        input += line+"\n";
    }

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(D and A\\s).*?(Testing(1|2)\\- End)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("MATCHED:\n" + m.group());
    }
```

gives

> MATCHED:
>   D and A
>   Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1 Testing1- End
>
> MATCHED:
>   D and A
>   Testing2  Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2 Testing2- End

Comment: Things are not working in my case please check My code is follow

Comment: Things are not working in my case please check My code is follow <pre><code> public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
       }//  readFileAsString() is contain data from file
        String stringdata = readFileAsString(); 
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(D and A\\s).*?(Testing(1|2)\\- End)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(stringdata);
        while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("MATCHED:\n" + m.group());
    }
    }
</pre></code>

Comment: I have updated my answer, I have tested the code it works on the input that you described.