# Extract paragraphs that match a given pattern from file, regex

Tags: java, regex, file-io

I have a huge text file which contains around 5000 comments in this form:

> D123456\tPOS/NEG\n Multiple lines of text go here. \n
>   D654321\tPOS/NEG\n Multiple lines of text go here. \n

...and so on.

And I need to extract them one by one. I have found this:
 [Best way to extract specific paragraph from file data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726826/best-way-to-extract-specific-paragraph-from-file-data) , which helped a little (using patterns, matcher). So my regex should be something like:

> D[0-9]{6}\t(POS|NEG)\n*\n

but this is not correct. How should it look like? By words: Starts with a 'D' then six numbers then a tab then POS or NEG then new line then basically anything then a new line.

Comment: what separates each comment? a double line break or just a single line break again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This this regex:

```
(?s)D[0-9]{6}\\t(POS|NEG.*?\n\n
```

Comment: out of interest, what does (?s) do?

Comment: @OGHaza: `(?s)` is for `Pattern.DOTALL` that makes DOT match newlines a well.

Answer (score 0):

```
D[0-9]{6}\t(POS|NEG)\n(.*?\n?)*?(?=D[0-9]{6}|$)
```

I wasn't sure what separated each comment, so I've got it matching the "multiple lines of text" as anything up until the next D000000 number, or the end of the file.

[Working on regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=D%5B0-9%5D%7B6%7D%5Ct%28POS%7CNEG%29%5Cn%28.%2a%3F%5Cn%3F%29%2a%3F%28%3F%3DD%5B0-9%5D%7B6%7D%7C%24%29&input=D123456%09POS%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.%20%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.%20%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.%20%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.%20%0AD654321%09NEG%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.%20%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.%20%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.%20%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.%20%0AD654321%09NEG%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.%20%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.%20%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.%20%0AMultiple%20lines%20of%20text%20go%20here.)