# Extract paragraph sample from file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-tika, nlp

I have an unknown file type uploaded. It can be doc, pdf, xls, etc.

My ultimate goal is to:

1. Determine if there are paragraphs of text in the file (as opposed to, say, a bunch of picture captions or text from a chart or table)
2. If (1) is true and there are paragraphs of text, extract a few sample paragraphs from the file.

I know that I can use a program like [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) to extract the file to a `String`.

However, I would like to also get the format of the extracted text and determine where there are paragraphs of full, written text (as opposed to captions, etc.).

So I also would like a way to analyze the extracted text. Specifically, I would like a library that can identify full, written paragraphs, as opposed to text that was simply taken from things like photo captions, charts, etc.

While Tika is a rather large library, I would be willing to add it if it can perform the tasks that I need.

However, I can not find anything in Tika that would allow me to analyze the structure of the text in such a way.

Is there something I missed?

Other than Tika, I am aware of some API’s for analyzing text, specifically [Comprehend](https://aws.amazon.com/comprehend/features/) or Textract, but I still couldn't find something that can ensure the extraction of full, written paragraphs as I require.

I am looking for any suggestion using the libraries I listed above or others. Again, I'd like to avoid things like photo captions and such and only get text that was part of full, written paragraphs.

Is there any library that can help me with this or will I have to code the logic myself (for detecting paragraphs as well as detecting the difference between full paragraphs and text that was extracted from charts and captions)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to extract specific paragraph from file data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726826/best-way-to-extract-specific-paragraph-from-file-data)

Comment: Why not ask Apache Tika to give you the contents as XHTML, and then look at how it's grouped/formatted?

Comment: Thanks, when you say "look at how it's grouped", do you mean actually look myself? Is there a way to detect what I'm asking with code? How will the XHTML be different for regular text paragraphs vs photo captions, charts and the like?